# Categorising SharePoint list items on a HTML using Javascript and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint

I have a JavaScript page which is querying a SharePoint list. The information on the list regards IT hardware, Lap Tops, Tablets etc. The user inputs the specific type, and I have a drop down of more general hardware types.

This is what I've got:

[image: Current - All devices listed at same level]

and this is what I need:

[image: Future - Devices categorized as laptops, desktops, tablets]

So under the hardware headings the specifics get categorised. What's the best way to do this? JavaScript below:

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtLifeCycles = "";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
var imgDevicePicture = "";
var tempLCS2 = "";
 var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";

var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;



        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.DevicetypeValue;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;
        var DeviceImage = item.DeviceImage;



        txtTitle = "<p>"; //+ LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
        imgDevicePicture = "<img src='" + DeviceImage + "'>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
    $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/sites/IT/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");
    $('.deviceimage').append(imgDevicePicture); 

});





call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Comment: It's worth mentioning that currently the value of the drop down is stored in this variable:   var DeviceKind = item.DevicetypeValue;

Comment: I'm wondering if I could use an If statement to achieve this? So I've hardcoded the categories in the HTML. Could I create an If statement which would store the choice from the drop down, Laptop/Desktop/Tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You're taking records from a SharePoint list and displaying them grouped by a common column value. There are two ways to accomplish this.

### Option 1: Perform Separate Queries

If you have three categories of devices (e.g. Laptop, Desktop, and Tablet) you can query the SharePoint list once for each category of items you wish to retrieve.

```
var urlEndpoint = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices$expand=Priority,Devicetype&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + " and ";
var laptopFilter = "DevicetypeValue eq 'Laptop'",
    desktopFilter = "DevicetypeValue eq 'Desktop'",
    tabletFilter = "DevicetypeValue eq 'Tablet'";
$.ajax({
    url: urlEndpoint + laptopFilter,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }       
}).done(displayLaptopResults);

$.ajax({
    url: urlEndpoint + desktopFilter,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }       
}).done(displayDesktopResults);

$.ajax({
    url: urlEndpoint + tabletFilter,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }       
}).done(displayTabletResults);

function displayLaptopResults(data){ /* your code here */ }
function displayDesktopResults(data){ /* your code here */ }
function displayTabletResults(data){ /* your code here */ }
```

This is only possible if you know the different categories beforehand and can compose your queries to filter against those categories. It has the advantage of working with smaller chunks of data at a time, and might be necessary when dealing with large lists.

If you don't know all the possible categories then consider the next option.

### Option 2: Perform One Query and Post-process The Results

Alternatively, you can get all the results and place them into an in-memory data structure according to their category before displaying the records on the page.

Instead of having an array of items...

```
var results = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]
```

You'll have a hashmap with an array property for each category.

```
var results = {
 category1: [item1, item4],
 category2: [item2, item3],
 category3: [item5]
}
```

The following code example demonstrates how you can process an array of items to categorize them, then render the results afterwards.

```js
var data = {d:{results:[
  {title:"X1 Carbon",DevicetypeValue:"laptop"},
  {title:"T470",DevicetypeValue:"laptop"},
  {title:"MS Surface Pro3",DevicetypeValue:"tablet"},
  {title:"X270",DevicetypeValue:"laptop"},  
  {title:"M910",DevicetypeValue:"desktop"},  
  {title:"MS Surface Pro4",DevicetypeValue:"tablet"}]}};
var i = 0, len = data.d.results.length, item, category, devicesByCategory = {};

// loop through the results and add them to the devicesByCategory object
while(i < len){
  item = data.d.results[i];
  category = item.DevicetypeValue;
  if(devicesByCategory[category]){ 
    // if devicesByCategory already has an array for this item's category, add the item to it
    devicesByCategory[category].push(item);
  }else{
    // otherwise, create a new array for the category
    devicesByCategory[category] = [item];
  }
  i++;
}

// loop through all the categories and render them
for(var category in devicesByCategory){
  var div = createCategorySection(category);
  addResultsToSection(div,devicesByCategory[category]); 
}

function createCategorySection(value){
     var div = document.getElementById("output").appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
     div.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")).appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
     return div;
}

function addResultsToSection(section,results){
  var ul = section.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
  i = 0; len = results.length;
  while(i < len){
    item = results[i];
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).appendChild(document.createTextNode(item.title));
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: With the first option would I have to have the var query = "..." and var urlEndpoint = "..."? Or could I just use one?

Comment: Also what code would I put into 
     function displayLaptopResults(data){ ?

Comment: I've got:

$('#laptopFilter').append("<ul>+ 'laptopFilter'</ul>");


   }
function displayDesktopResults(data){   
$('#sesktopFilter').append("<ul>+ 'desktopFilter'</ul>");

  }
function displayTabletResults(data){ 
$('#tabletFilter').append("<ul>+ 'tabletFilter'</ul>");